# How to create a Loop for this? Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am relatively new to VBA. I wanted to create this loop for a macro that would circulate through all worksheets within the workbook. Essentially what I am trying to do is to change all the dates in the "G" Column to change from 8/15/2018 to 201808 (yyyymm). Here is the recorded macro:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "yyyymm"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: So, nobody knows what you try to acomplish. Can you please tell us what you want to do exept writing a loog for something on some sheet with a date format? ;)

Comment: @Lutscha Sorry about that! Let me edit the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can loop the worksheets collection to apply to each sheet the formatting for that column. Using the worksheets collection has the advantage of avoiding any chart sheets you may have in the workbook.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ApplyFormatting()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Columns("G:G").NumberFormat = "yyyymm"
    Next
End Sub
```

---

If you have string rather than dates you could try converting the string to date format e.g.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ApplyFormatting()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, inputArray(), lastRow As Long
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws.Columns("G:G")
            lastRow = ws.Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
            inputArray = ws.Range("G1:G" & lastRow).Value
            inputArray = ProcessArray(inputArray)
            .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(inputArray, 1), UBound(inputArray, 2)) = inputArray
            .NumberFormat = "yyyymm"
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Public Function ProcessArray(ByRef inputArray As Variant) As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(inputArray, 1) To UBound(inputArray, 1)
        inputArray(i, 1) = GetDate(inputArray(i, 1))
    Next
    ProcessArray = inputArray
End Function

Public Function GetDate(ByVal dateString As String) As String
    Dim arr() As String
    If dateString = vbNullString Or Not InStr(dateString, "/") > 0 Then
        GetDate = vbNullString
    Else
        arr = Split(dateString, "/")
        GetDate = Format$(DateSerial(arr(2), arr(0), arr(1)), "yyyy-mm-dd")
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Did you put the code in a standard module? And are the sheets in the same workbook as the code that you want to format?

Comment: Yes, All of the worksheets are in the same workbook. And the code itself is all within one module

Comment: Are you working with actual dates in column G or are they text strings? You can test with ISNUMBER( cell) If text string s then you need to do some additional work.

Comment: there is a chance it could be Text strings. How would I double check?

Comment: choose one say it was A1 then in B1 you would put ISNUMERIC(A1)

Comment: If they are strings are they in a consistent format and is that format 8/15/2018  ?